# Recyclerview problem with multiple spinner problem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I have 2 spinners in my recycler view. Now my 2nd spinner value depends on the 1st spinner selected item.

I am able to bind data in spinner 1 but when I try to bind spinner 2 data based on setOnItemSelectedListener of spinner 1 it will only bind for a visible item on the screen.

I want to bind spinner 2 data even if it is not visible on the screen. I have the following code for the adapter :

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<MainDetails> mMainDetails;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomerAdapter(Context mcontext, ArrayList<MainDetails> mainDetails) {
        mContext = mcontext;
        mMainDetails = mainDetails;
    }


    private Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_bind_data, viewGroup, false);
        return new CardViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder cardViewHolder, int position) {

        final MainDetails testMainDetails = mMainDetails.get(position);

        ArrayAdapter<Products> spinnerUserAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Products>(getContext(), R.layout.dropdown_item, testMainDetails.getUsers());
        spinnerUserAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cardViewHolder.spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerUserAdapter);

        cardViewHolder.spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try {
                    Products pp = (Products) parent.getSelectedItem();
                    ArrayAdapter<Orders> spinnerPPAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Orders>(getContext(), R.layout.pc_estimator_dropdown_item, pp.getOrders());
                    spinnerPPAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    cardViewHolder.spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerPPAdapter);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        cardViewHolder.spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               //other operation
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMainDetails.size();
    }


    public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public Spinner spinner1;
        public Spinner spinner2;

        public CardViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            spinner1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spinner2 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        }
    }
}
```

My spinner `cardViewHolder.spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener` method only calls for visible items on screens but I want to bind all data even if it not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement everything inside ViewHolder. Let me show you an example:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SomeHolder holder, int position) {
        if (SomeDataList.size() > 0) {
            SomeData data = SomeDataList.get(position);
            holder.bindData(data);
        }
    }
```

Then in holder class:

```
public class SomeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final TextView tvAddress;
    private final TextView tvAccountNumber;
    private final TextView tvName;

    private SomeData someData;

    public SomeHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvAccountNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_point_account_number);
        tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_point_subscr_name);
        tvAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_point_address);
       
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bindData(SomeData data) {
        someData = data;
        tvAddress.setText(data.getAddress());
        //other stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (someData!=null){
           tvName.setText(someData.getName());
            //code for click event
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really know what SPINNER is? Just posting your random m file code in stack overflow.

Comment: maybe yes or I just posting your random m file code in stack overflow

Comment: Or I just advised to write some code another way to make it more readable. Or I needed to urgently get away from writing an answer, and then I forgot to finish it. I just do not remember

Answer (score 0):

straight inside `onBindViewHolder` you are setting only one adapter, for `spinner1` and nothing for `spinner2` - it got its adapter only after `onItemSelected` call of `spinner1`

if you want to set some initial values for `spinner2` you have to initiate its adapter inside `onBindViewHolder`, not only in `onItemSelected`

move your adapter initiation code to separated method

```
public void setUpSpinner2(Spinner spinner, Products pp) {
    try {
        ArrayAdapter<Orders> spinnerPPAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Orders>(getContext(), R.layout.pc_estimator_dropdown_item, pp.getOrders());
        spinnerPPAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerPPAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e.toString());
    }
}
```

then inside `onItemSelected` call it

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Products pp = (Products) parent.getSelectedItem();
    setUpSpinner2(cardViewHolder.spinner2, pp);
}
```

and also call `setUpSpinner2` straight inside `onBindViewHolder` with `null` check (is item selected on start)

```
if (spinnerUserAdapter.getSelectedItem() != null) {
    Products pp = (Products) spinnerUserAdapter.getSelectedItem();
    setUpSpinner2(cardViewHolder.spinner2, pp);
}
```

---

btw. I see you aren't storing `spinner1` selected value anywhere, so after recycling both spinners will be empty again. so inside `onItemSelected` get position of selected item (there is method `getSelectedItemPosition`) and store it in some array

```
//top of adapters code
private ArrayList<MainDetails> mMainDetails;
private Context mContext;
private SparseArray<Integer> selectedItemsForPositions = new SparseArray<>();
```

inside `onItemSelected` and `onNothingSelected` put/clear selected value with this line (don't mix positions of `onBindViewHolder` and `onItemSelected`, name them differently)

```
selectedItemsForPositions.put(onBindViewHolderPosition, parent.getSelectedItemPosition());
// or put null if nothing selected
```

when you have this array which is keeping selected positions then restore this position just after `spinner1` adapter set up

```
cardViewHolder.spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerUserAdapter);
Integer selectedPosition = selectedItemsForPositions.get(onBindViewHolderPosition);
if(selectedPosition != null) spinnerUserAdapter.setSelection(selectedPosition);
```